# How can I load data inside elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I create a dictionary, when I tried to load data in ES I get this ERROR,
Please can someone explain what is mean the ERROR?

```
    final_adress = {}
      for i in DF['adress'].unique():
        final_adress[i] = [{"service": DF.service[j], "Number of person": DF.num_person[j], "Number of rooms": DF.num_room[j]} for j in DF[DF.adress==i].index]
      print final_adress
es = Elasticsearch([ipES])
es.index(index="*****, doc_type='timeWindow', body=final_adress)
except Exception as e:
  logFile.write("Can't load data into ElasticSearch: {}\n".format(str(e)))
```

ERROR:

```
Can't load data into ElasticSearch: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u"failed to parse field [adresse.01.15.22] of type [long] in document with id 'z4ibZGsBFBLhne6XSvuE'")
    'postecode'
```

Sometimes the ERROR:

```
Can't load data into ElasticSearch: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'object mapping for [final_adress] tried to parse field [final_adress] as object, but found a concrete value')
'postecode'
```

Comment: You need to show more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: This error may indicate that you're trying to import something which isn't of type `long` (Large integer). Are you potentially importing a string value instead? Might be worth double checking that data.

Comment: @Matt, I m importing string and int